# How to query Blackberry contact with UID?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to search UID in the native Contacts. I have the UID of a particular Contact, now I want to update all those Contacts that match this UID which I have in my DB. My main aim is to stop the duplication of Contacts which I insert. Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey got the Answers of my own question.. Thanks for all your efforts. By using your UID no. you can just call this Method

```
contact = (BlackBerryContact) contactsList.getByUID(uid, 1);
```

Pass your uid and do the same as you are doing for Retrieving the contact with Phone number.